# c# Lambda Expression List of strings

Tags: c#, lambda

I m confused about How can i Find a Specified Text In a A List using Lambda Expressions 
For Example i have a List

```
List<string> MyList = new List<string> {"TEXT","NOTEXT","test","notest"};
```

as you can see The List is Filtred By "ToUpper" and "ToLower" Properties 
i want for example to shearch on **ToLower** elemtes in this list using Lambda Expression

```
var SList = MyList.FindAll(item => item.ToLower);
foreach(var s in SList)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(s);
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if the lowercase value matches against the current value, same for upper

```
var lower = MyList.Where(a=>a == a.ToLowerInvariant());
var upper = MyList.Where(a=>a == a.ToUpperInvariant());
```

If you want to use the culture specific version to check then just use the culture-specific methods

```
var lower = MyList.Where(a=>a == a.ToLower());
var upper = MyList.Where(a=>a == a.ToUpper());
```

Comment: @bakapanda No problem, please mark as the answer if this has resolved your issue

Answer (score 0):

`ToLower` is not a property but a method and it does not make a test (i.e it does not return a `bool`) but returns a converted string.

This means, that since it is a method, you must place parentheses after it (`.ToLower()`).

In order to make a test you must compare the result with something. In this case with the original string, in order to see whether it is equal to the lower case string.

```
var SList = MyList.FindAll(item => item == item.ToLower());
```

The exact working of `ToLower` depends on the current UI-culture. Some languages have special rules for conversion to lower or upper case. If you prefer to have a culture independent behavior, use `ToLowerInvariant` or `ToUpperInvariant` instead.